# Can I use Google Maps API and substitute Openstreet map as base layer?

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap, google-maps-api

This Question is based on below requirements.

1 - our application will need to use functionalities of Google Maps API like custom marker/Info pop up/Routing etc.

2 - our application wants to use Openstreetmaps or our ownmaps as the base layer.

Now , can we use Google maps API for functionalities and Openstreet map as base layer,so that I am not charged for using google data ? do they specifically charge for API usage ? isnt the 2500 request limit for http requests to google image/map server ?

Adarsh

Comment: You are better of using Openlayers - custom markers info pop can be achieved using it. Certain Google functions (geocoding) has to be returned on the google map or it breaks the terms and conditions.

Comment: http://www.openlayers.org/dev/examples/osm-marker-popup.html

Comment: Hi Mapperz, Do you think openlayers can be integrated with existing PHP based web applciation ? I researched quite considerable time and only example I came across with straight results http://www.ns-tech.co.uk/demo/parallel-track/?demo=1

Comment: OpenLayers can be used with php and javascript. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958085/receive-post-request-in-php-from-openlayers-javascript

Answer (score 1):

Check the Directions API [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Limits) page which says:

> Note: the Directions API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; using Directions data without displaying a map for which directions data was requested is prohibited

I believe that means you'll need to use the Google Maps API for your basemaps if you also wish to use their routing capability.

Answer (score 0):

you can use google maps as layer, e.g., http://sautter.com/map/. or you can use layers (jquery) to render google routing on the top of openstreet maps. 
Why you don't use open routing with openstreet map, look at http://sautter.com/map/

Comment: Technically you can probably do this - legally, you can't. The [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#Limits) states "Note: the Directions API may only be used in conjunction with displaying results on a Google map; using Directions data without displaying a map for which directions data was requested is prohibited"

Comment: @ Stephen , @ Amjad  Showing routes/directions is not a priority, our purpose is live tracking of vehicles and showing them over an open street map with Google markers and API functionality.  We did this successfully using the http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Google_Maps_Example , but somehow, the markers ( for vehicles) wont show on top of openstreet maps .. Hope there is some clarity in the requirements